# Not getting asked for permission Write External

Tags: android, file, io, android-permissions

I am quite new to using Android Studio and I keep running into this problem about permissions.

I would simply like my App to on start create a simple .txt file somewhere on the external memory.

However I can't seem the permissions to work. Whenever I try to create a file it throws an exception.

My manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.freddefrallan.pleasework">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

When I start the App in an AVD it gives me zero feedback on asking for permission.
And this functions returns false.

```
private boolean checkWriteExternalPermission()
{
    String permission = "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE";
    int res = getApplicationContext().checkCallingOrSelfPermission(permission);
    return (res == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
}
```

Comment: Are you running on a Android 6.0+ devices? Is your targetSdkVersion 23 or higher?

Comment: What is the exception you get?

Comment: If you are targeting 6.0+ - Check the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) on how to request permission at runtime

Comment: Thank you! I ended up using runtime requests and it worked buttery smooth!